# Get variable from a function in a class

Tags: php, function, class

I want to get a variable from a class in a function , the variable has arrays and i want to print all of theme in foreach loop

Here is my code :

```
class MP {

    public function mp_setup_fields() {

        $fields_socialmedia = array(
            array(
                'label' => 'شبکه های اجتماعی',
                'id' => '',
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'section' => 'mp_custom_section',
            ),
        );

    }

}
```

I want get $fields_socialmedia in my home page

Comment: You're using the wrong variable for the `foreach`.

Comment: Sorry i edited my code @FunkFortyNiner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MP {

    public function mp_setup_fields() {

        $fields_socialmedia = array(
            array(
                'label' => 'شبکه های اجتماعی',
                'id' => '',
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'section' => 'mp_custom_section',
            ),
        );
        return $fields_socialmedia;

    }

}
```

At first create object of your class then call method of object like below

```
    $mp = new MP();
    $array =  $mp->mp_setup_fields();

    foreach ($array as $value){
        foreach ($value as $key => $v){
            echo $key ."=". $v;
        }

}
```